# fileInfo[] array in listbox

Tags: c#, linq, listbox

I am using this code to search through a directory for files with certain parameters put in place although some of them can be left blank, hence the '||' within the code. we are using the Linq function.

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(@"c:\Work\TestDirectory");
IEnumerable<System.IO.FileInfo> fileList = dir.GetFiles("*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);


string stringSearch = string.Empty;
//string stringSearch = "test";

DateTime? dateSearch = null;
//DateTime? dateSearch = new DateTime(2016, 1, 1);

string fileType = string.Empty;
//string fileType = ".txt";

IEnumerable<System.IO.FileInfo>
fileQuery =
from file in fileList
where (
//Search value for name is NULL or FileName contains the search string
(string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringSearch) || file.Name.Contains(stringSearch))

//AND Search date is null or File Last Access time was before search date
&& ((!dateSearch.HasValue) || file.LastAccessTime < dateSearch.Value)

//AND Search file type is null or File extension = search type
&& (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileType) || file.Extension.Equals(fileType))

//Modified before
&& ((!dateSearch.HasValue) || file.LastWriteTime < dateSearch.Value)

//Modified After
&& ((!dateSearch.HasValue) || file.LastWriteTime > dateSearch.Value)

//etc
)
orderby file.Name
select file;

//Execute the query. 
foreach (System.IO.FileInfo fi in fileQuery) ;
{
listBox1.Items.Add(fileList);
}

        }
    }
}
```

When I click on my search button i get "fileInfo[] array" in my listbox. can anybody help me with why this happens?
Thanks

Comment: change `listBox1.Items.Add(fileList);` to `listBox1.Items.Add(fi);`

Comment: apparently fi does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `.Add()` to add a single item

`listbox1.Items.Add(fi);`

or use `.AddRange()` to add a list of items

`listBox1.Items.AddRange(fileQuery.ToList());`

refer the msdn link for more info https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z018s5az%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: the first solution, says fi does not exist in the current context and the second throws up a lot of errors

Comment: do remove the `;` in the foreach line

Comment: do you know why when i enter in certain parameters it still throws back every file in the directory?